# How to serialize deserialize mongo document in php?

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to save some mongo documents to json file (It's something like backup). So when I'm trying to do this, I always got json with:

```
"_id":{"$oid":"..."}
```

or

```
"createdAt":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"...."}}}
```

So, what I need to do or how I can get correct "_id" and "createdAt" ? I mean It should be ObjectId and ISODate.

```
"_id" : ObjectId(""),
"createdAt" : ISODate("2016-05-..."),
```

Comment: [`MongoDB\BSON\fromJSON `](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mongodb.bson-fromjson.php) it's part of the installed driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clean way to serialize/unserialize bson is to extend your model/class to implement `MongoDB\BSON\Persistable`:

```php
class MyModel implements MongoDB\BSON\Persistable{

    public function bsonSerialize()
    {
        return [
            'field1' => $this->field1,
            'date1' => new UTCDateTime($this->dateTimeDate->getTimestamp()*1000)
        ];
    }

    public function bsonUnserialize(array $data){
         $this->field1 = $data['field1'];
         $this->dateTimeDate = $data['date1']->toDateTime();
    }
}
```

Having that implementation the serialization is done "automatically", so you can use it as follows:

```php
//get document from mongodb
 $document = $this->mycollection->findOne(array('id' => $id->toString())); //parsed class MyModel is returned.

//insert document into mongodb
$this->mycollection->insertOne($myentity); //class is mapped to bson
```

To get the class serialized as `JSON` you can additionally implement the interface `JsonSerializable` and work with `json_decode`/`json_encode`.